# Extend Visual Studio 2012 Test Explorer with extra information

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012

As part of some research I am writing an extension for the Microsoft Visual Studio Unit Testing Framework with a custom testing type, like described [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vstsqualitytools/archive/2009/09/04/extending-the-visual-studio-unit-test-type-part-1.aspx). I have created a custom attribute, but I want to show some additional information in the Test Explorer about the executed test from my custom attribute.

I was also wondering if there is any way to show information of all unit tests (so from my custom attribute, but also from the default Visual Studio Unit Testing Framework attributes) that were executed in the past. So I can show the information from these tests in graphs etc.

Does anybody know a good solution to achieve this?

**UPDATE 1**
What I mean is something like this:

[image]

Comment: Can you provide an example of what you're trying to achieve? I'm afraid I don't really understand what you're trying to do here. If you want to log any information, you should be able to do so through `TestContext.WriteLine`. If you want to time something, you should be able to do so through `TestContext.Begin/EndTimer` and if you want to add a file to the test results, you can use `TestConext.AddFile` anything in particular you're after? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.testtools.unittesting.testcontext.aspx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Console.WriteLine did the job... The user can click on 'output' and sees the output...

Comment: That's interesting. I never knew you could write info from the test and view it on the results.

Answer (score 7):

Are you trying to show additional traits of tests in the Test Explorer? If so, you can use the "Group by Traits" supported added in the Visual Studio 2012 Update 1 (ref detail at http://blogs.msdn.com/b/somasegar/archive/2012/11/26/visual-studio-2012-update-1-now-available.aspx, download from http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=35774).

In short, you can decorate your test with something like

```
    [TestMethod]
    [TestCategory("SpecialTestType")]
    [TestProperty("XXX","YYY")]
    public void TestMethod1()
    {
    }
```

Once this test is discovered again, choose "Group By Traits" (toolbar in the TextExplorer tool window) shall group tests based on your traits (e.g. SpecialTestType, XXX).

Comment: Thanks, I think I can use this as well, but is not exactly what I was looking for. I've updated my question